# Load new activity after 5 seconds

Tags: java, android, android-activity, timer

Hi I have been searching for ways to get my android app to load StartActivity.java for 5 seconds and then load into MainActivity.java once 5 seconds is up. Any examples i have found havent worked for me. So wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

StartActivity.java

```
package com.example.testerrquin.euro2016fanguide;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }

    }.start();
}}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testerrquin.euro2016fanguide" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.`

Comment: What about using a CountDownTimer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out. It works in my application.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent start = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(start);
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected int SECONDS = 5;
    Handler handler = new Handler();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long currentMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SECONDS--;
            if (SECONDS > 0) {
                handler.postAtTime(this, currentMilliseconds);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
            } else {
                Intent it = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(it);
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };  
}
```

The main tricks is made by using `handler.postDelayed`

Hope its helps!!

Comment: It runs the startactivity and loads for 5 seconds but after 5 seconds when new activity is opened it crashes out

Comment: Umm...thats very rare, this code is part of already 30 apps where I've been working for 2 years,most of them are published in google playstore, so I'm very curious, where is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the finish() and try it again

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(startNewActivity);

   }
}, 5000);
```